# Date formatting not working in Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, datetime, date

I am trying to convert the date in a date field to different time zones using format method. But it is not getting converted. Below is the sample code.

```
Account acc = [select id, custom_date__c from Account where custom_date__c != null limit 1];

datetime dateee = acc.custom_date__c ;

system.debug('date1 -- '+dateee);
dateee.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss','America/New_York');
system.debug('date2 -- '+dateee);
dateee.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss','GMT');
system.debug('date3 -- '+dateee);
dateee.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss','Australia/Sydney');
system.debug('date4 -- '+dateee);
```

**custom_date__c**  is a **Date** field. I am not concerned with the timestamp. I tried by declaring '**dateee**' variable as **Date** and **DateTime** both. But nothing is working and the **dateee** variable is not getting converted. I am trying this piece of code in anon window. Does it make any difference ?

Below is the debug log.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Format returns a new string. You need to assign the value to a new variable.

```
Account acc = [select id, custom_date__c from Account where custom_date__c != null limit 1];

datetime dateee = acc.custom_date__c ;
String formattedString = dateee.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
System.debug(formattedString);
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox. Can't understand why it is not showing the value when directly used in syste.debug()

Comment: @Sfdc_Spider `system.debug(dateee.format(...));` will work, but in your example code you aren't directly formatting in a `system.debug()`. `DateTime.format()` does not alter the Datetime it is called on. Also, because you're starting with a `Date` instead of a `DateTime`, the time component is treated as `00:00:00`. Thus, the date will only change (and only to the previous day) when you use a time zone behind UTC (e.g. UTC -4)